# Sql UPDATE with automatical INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a setting like this

```
CREATE TABLE Mother (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Kitten (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   mother_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Mother
);
```

The Kitten table is filled and some of them have a reference to a mother but some doesn't have. The tables may look like:

```
== Mother ==
| 1 |
| 2 |

== Kitten ==
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 |    1 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 |    2 |
| 5 |    1 |
| 6 | NULL |
```

Now (due to some requirement changes) every Kitten must have a mother which should just be created. I tried the following which *doesn't work*.

```
UPDATE Kitten
SET mother_id = (
  INSERT INTO Mother DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id
)
WHERE mother_id IS NULL;
```

Error is

```
Fehler in der SQL-Abfrage: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 3: INSERT INTO Mother DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id
```

Using PosgreSQL 9.3.5

Auto-increment-Comment: The combination of "serial" and "primary key" enables auto-increment by default

Here is the sql snipped to create the described database state:

```
drop table if exists Kitten;
drop table if exists Mother;

CREATE TABLE Mother (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Kitten (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  mother_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Mother
);

insert into Mother default values;
insert into Mother default values;

insert into Kitten (mother_id) values (NULL);
insert into Kitten (mother_id) values (1);
insert into Kitten (mother_id) values (NULL);
insert into Kitten (mother_id) values (2);
INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (NULL);
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new mother for **each** kitten that has none? (so 2 new mothers based on your sample data), or **only one** mother that is used for both orphaned kittens (which is what the syntax you have tried to use would suggest)

Comment: yes for every Kitten a new Mother

Answer (score 1):

If you need one mother per orphan kitten, you can do the following:

```
with
  orphans as ( -- find the orphans and record their ids, ordered
    select id, row_number() over ()
    from kitten
    where mother_id is null
    ),
  newmothers as ( -- insert as many new mothers as needed, return new ids
    insert into mother
    select nextval('mother_id_seq')
    from orphans
    returning id
    ),
  newmothers2 as ( -- add row number for all new mother ids
    select *, row_number() over ()
    from newmothers
    )
update kitten k set
  mother_id = m.id
from orphans o
join newmothers2 m using (row_number) -- join orphans with new mothers
where o.id = k.id
```

Comment: I get: ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" LINE 9: select from orphans ... I've added an sql snipped to reproduce my database

Comment: @Marcel I updated the script replacing `motherid` with `mother_id`. It works in my PostgreSQL 9.5, I'll check if any part of the code is incompatible with 9.3

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister pg-9.3 doesn't seem to like the empty lists in `insert into mother select from orphans`

Comment: @joop should work now, it's inserting using the sequence's nextval now instead of an empty list

Comment: That is the only possible workaround, so it seems (DEFAULT (VALUE) doesn't work either)

Comment: I just updated to version 9.5.3 but I still get "ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" LINE 10: from orphans"

Comment: @Marcel oops, there was an extra comma at the end of nextval, my bad. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I found a pure SQL solution which works for me. It uses a temporary column on mother-side.

```
-- prepare situation (same like in the question)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Kitten; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Mother;
CREATE TABLE Mother (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Kitten (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,mother_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Mother);
INSERT INTO Mother DEFAULT VALUES;INSERT INTO Mother DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (NULL);INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (1);INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (NULL);INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (2);INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (1);INSERT INTO Kitten (mother_id) VALUES (NULL);

-- create temporarily "bidirectionality"
-- by creating a reference from mother to kitten
ALTER TABLE mother ADD kitten_id INTEGER;

-- create new Mothers for motherless kittens with reference to this kitten
INSERT INTO mother (kitten_id)
  (SELECT id FROM kitten WHERE mother_id IS NULL);

-- update kittens 
UPDATE kitten SET mother_id =
  (SELECT id FROM mother WHERE mother.kitten_id = kitten.id)
WHERE mother_id IS NULL;

-- remove temporary column
ALTER TABLE mother DROP kitten_id;

-- make sure this never happens again
ALTER TABLE kitten ALTER mother_id SET NOT NULL;

-- show results
SELECT kitten.id AS Kitten_Id , mother.id AS Mother_Id FROM kitten, mother WHERE kitten.mother_id = mother.id ORDER BY Kitten_id
```